# how to find out the configured maximum of java heap size?

Tags: heap-memory, java-opts

I am working on windows system and configure the maximum of java heap size in my java application like this:

> JavaOptions= -Xmx6G

in the .proberties file.

**Question 1:** How to verify that this change is taking place? is it possible from the cmd?

**Question 2:**  I know that I can configure the max java heap as 4G on 32bit system. What is the maximum on 64bit system? 8G?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't have a Windows machine, but this should do it. `tasklist | FIND "java"`
2. There's no limit on 64-bit systems, it's only limited by your system memory.